# Unable to load Jpeg Image file using App.js in React

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

While trying out the following code to load an image file to imgur, using React, ran into problems. The code simply looks for a file `test.jpeg`, and loads to imgur using imgur's API. App.js starts up with splash screen, as its using (create-react-app) but no file is loaded, the code is as below:

```js
class App extends Component {
  uploadImage() {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

    const fd = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const Data = new FormData();
    const e = document.getElementsByClassName('Image');
    var t;

    Data.append("image", e);
    fd.open("POST", "https://api.imgur.com/3/image/");

    fd.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Client ID XXXXSecret");
    fd.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (fd.status === 200 && fd.readyState === 4) {
        let result = JSON.parse(fd.responseText);
        t = "https://i.imgur.com/${result.data.id}.png";

        const d = document.createElement("div");
        d.className = "image";
        document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d);
      }
    };

    fd.send(Data);
  }
 render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
    </header>
    <img src={Image} className="ImageFile" alt="Image"/>    
<p className="App-intro">
      To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
  <button onClick={this.uploadImage} width="200" height="200">Button </button>
  <p></p>
  </div>
);
  }
}
export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a handful of things wrong here.

1. Nothing calls `uploadImage()`, so of course nothing will happen.
2. Doing `Data.append("image", "test.jpeg");` will add a field called `image`, with a string payload `"test.jpeg"`, not an image called `test.jpeg`.
3. If you expect this to be an user-supplied image, you have to use an `<input type="file">` element and capture the `File` object from its `files` list property. There is no other way of accessing user content.

Comment: Thanks, for reply, actually I am getting a list of  image files,  which is in json, after the user chooses one file the chosen  file is to be sent using the api,